# PHP Авторизоваться на странице с помощью guzzlehttp

Tags: php, guzzle

Не получается авторизоваться на сайте с помощью `guzzlehttp`.
Получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://python.su/account/signin/` resulted in a `403 FORBIDDEN` response:

При включенном дебаге:

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error

Код:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

  $client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://python.su',  
        'allow_redirects' => true,            
        'headers' => [                         
            'User-Agent'   => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux 3.4; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0',
            'Accept'       => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
        ]
  ]);

  $login = $client -> request('POST','/account/signin/',[
    'form_params' => [
       'backurl' => '/', 
      'email'    => 'llogin',
      'password'    => 'ppasword',
    ],
    'debug' => false    
  ]);
  
  $cookie   = $login  -> getHeaderLine('Set-Cookie');  
  $discounts = $client -> request('GET','/',[
    'headers' => [ 
        'Cookie' => $cookie
    ] 
  ]);  
   
  $body = $discounts -> getBody() -> getContents();
  echo $body;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас посмотрел на указаном сайте, в POST запросе уходит не только логин и пароль, но и токен.

Получается как-то так:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: pQ7NzIYkGsaSPQkgFubtKopfvOjUhX2a
email: 45454
password: 5454
```

Email и password это то что я ввел в форме. А вот токен формируется автоматически. В вашем же скрипте этот токен не передается. Поэтому сайт и возвращает 403-ю ошибку.

По идее этот токет формируется автоматически и каждый раз он должен быть уникальным.

Т.е. алгоритм работы вашего скрипта должне быть следующим:

1. Зайти запросом GET на страницу с формой. Сохранить полученные cookie и так же вытащить из страницы токен.
2. Сделать POST запрос в котором передать токен и ваши логин и пароль. Так же передать корректные cookie, которые сохранили на предыдущем шаге.

Comment: получаю куки csrftoken=ygBieN3BBqbAfHP5NtJImyUbk8I58kK1; expires=Thu, 21-Dec-2023 10:11:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
из них надо выдрать токен ?

Comment: явно что то не так
`$cookie = $page_cook  -> getHeaderLine('Set-Cookie');  
  //Вырезаю из него ТОКЕН - cZymfR7nBfEOerAkxDm6g0jhXRRFrZIi
  $token = explode(";", $cookie);
  $token = explode("=", $token[0]);
  $token = $token[1];
  

  $login = $client -> request('POST','/account/signin/',[
 'headers' => [ 
      'Cookie' => $cookie,
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken' => $token
    ],
    'form_params' => [
      'email'    => 'llogin',
      'password'    => 'ppasword',
    ]  
  ]);`